# How to solve the error 'AttributeError: 'ir.http' object has no attribute 'webclient_rendering_context' - - -'?

Tags: database, webclient, attributeerror, odoo-13, odoo-server

I got this error when i try to run odoo via terminal after configuring odoo and python in eclipse and created database. Here is the full error reference.

```
2021-06-08 13:51:17,499 14016 ERROR odoo_13A werkzeug: Error on request:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "/home/davemax/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)

File "/home/davemax/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 258, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/service/server.py", line 439, in app
    return self.app(e, s)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 1287, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 1257, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)

File "/home/davemax/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 766, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 1457, in dispatch
    result = ir_http._dispatch()

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 238, in _dispatch
    return cls._handle_exception(e)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 206, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 750, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 234, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 809, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)

File "/home/davemax/odoo/workspace/odoo_13/odoo_13/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 844, in web_client
    context = request.env['ir.http'].webclient_rendering_context()

AttributeError: 'ir.http' object has no attribute 'webclient_rendering_context' - - -
```

This is the full trace back. Please help me.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: I have posted again the full trace back error above. Please help me.

Comment: Which version of odoo are you using?

Comment: I am using odoo 13 version

Answer (score 1):

run your server using : `-d cphhr_test -u all`
just like :

```
/home/sadid/venv/bin/python3 /home/sadid/odoo-bin -c /home/sadid/odoo.conf -d cphhr_test -u all
```